# Сalling SAP BAPI from the Android application

Tags: android-studio, sap

I am new to Android programming.
The task is as follows:

From an Android application (apk) connect remotely to SAP and call BAPI.
The option of calling via web-service is not suitable - the security system does not allow.

I need to connect SAP using **SAPROUTER**.

**System**:

1) Windows 8.1, - 64-bit

2) Java 1.8.0_201 - 64-bit

3) Android studio - 64-bit

4) SAP JCO libraries for **Windows 32-bit** (https://support.sap.com/en/product/connectors/jco.html)

**In Android Studio**:
- Created an activity and created a button.
- When clicking on the button, the method try connect to SAP.

**The code is as follows**:

```
Properties connectProperties = new Properties ();

connectProperties.setProperty (DestinationDataProvider.JCO_ASHOST, "xx.xx.xx.xx");

connectProperties.setProperty (DestinationDataProvider.JCO_SYSNR, "00");

connectProperties.setProperty (DestinationDataProvider.JCO_CLIENT, "200");

connectProperties.setProperty (DestinationDataProvider.JCO_USER, "USER_NAME");

connectProperties.setProperty (DestinationDataProvider.JCO_PASSWD, "USER_PASS");

connectProperties.setProperty (DestinationDataProvider.JCO_LANG, "EN");

connectProperties.setProperty (DestinationDataProvider.JCO_SAPROUTER, "/H/xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx...");

String f_name = createDestinationDataFile (context, DESTINATION_NAME1, connectProperties);

try {

    JCoDestination jcoDestination = JCoDestinationManager.getDestination (DESTINATION_NAME1);

    JCoFunction function = jcoDestination.getRepository().GetFunction ("ZGET_ANLA");

    if (function == null) throw new RuntimeException ("ZGET_ANLA not found in SAP.");

    System.out.println ("ok");

    } catch (JCoException e) {

      e.printStackTrace ();

    }

 static String createDestinationDataFile (Context context, String destinationName, Properties connectProperties)

   {

       PackageManager m = context.getPackageManager ();

       String str = context.getPackageName ();

       try {

           PackageInfo p = m.getPackageInfo (str, 0);

           str = p.applicationInfo.dataDir;

       } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {

           Log.w ("your tag", "Error Package name not found", e);

       }

       System.setProperty ("jco.destinations.dir", str);

       String f_name = String.valueOf (str + "/" + destinationName);

       File destCfg = new File (str + "/" + destinationName + ". JcoDestination");

       try

       {

           FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream (destCfg, false);

           connectProperties.store (fos, "for tests only!");

           fos.close ();

       }

       catch (Exception e)

       {

           throw new RuntimeException ("Unable to create the destination files", e);

       }

       return f_name;

   }
```

At programm execute, at string:

```
JCoDestination jcoDestination = JCoDestinationManager.getDestination (DESTINATION_NAME1);
```

I'm getting the error -> "**library" libdl.so.2 "not found"**

```
E / AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.z_fi.zinv_fa, PID: 8455
    java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: JCo initialization failed with java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libdl.so.2" not found
```

But the library `libdl.so.2` is not include in the SAP JCO archive. 
(I tried and found the file `libdl.so.2` in linux archives. But programm requested next file libdl.so.**3**, etc. indefinitely)

**Questions**:

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. Which version of SAP JCO I should download - for Linux or for Windows? 32-bit or 64-bit?
3. Where do I need to import the files of the SAP JCO archive? In the Project structure or in the Device File Explorer (c:\Users***\Documents\AndroidStudio**DeviceExplorer**) ?
4. Do I need to make settings on the SAP server when using SAp JCO? I don't have access to the SAP server at the OS level ...

Perhaps, maybe there is another option connect to the SAP from Android application?

Answer (score 0):

from your link provided 4) you have to install 32 bit version of java